# When should I store my data as JSON?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design, relational-database

This is one of the longer ones so buckle up :P!

Consider a users table. It has the ID, password, email, and some timestamps. Now, say I want to store more information, such as where they are based (or any other not-too-often retrieved piece of data). I can store it in a new column in the users table as JSON (pseudo-code)

```
{based_in: {address: "here", country:"xx", region: "great"}}
```

Or I could create a 1:1 related user_location table that stores that information.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_based_in` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Lastly, I could also create a 1:n related table (user_info) that can hold this data in a key-value format, e.g. `based_in_address`, `based_in_country`.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_meta_key_index` (`key`)
)
```

With the first approach, I can add new details about the user without having to modify the back-end - so that's cool. But I feel it gets messy fast as I add more details.

With the second approach, I guess I get better indexing but that means having to tweak the back end every time I want to store a new user detail.

With the third approach, I can also add new details (keys) without changing the back end - but this solution seems kinda ugly to me in that it'll generate a lot of rows and can't be related (in the example above, only the first two options make it clear that `based_in_address` and `based_in_country` belong to the same object `based_in`).

I could also do a hybrid approach combining both the first and third method; creating a 1:n table that stores JSON in its value column.

And then, lets say I'd also like to add their favourite colour :P - would it be a new table, new column, new row, or a new object?.

What approach would work best for not-so-often-retrieved related data (that is often subject to change as in new keys may be added to store other details) in terms of performance, scalability, and flexibility?

When do we create related tables rather than creating new columns for 1:1 relationships (especially since the advent of JSON in MySQL)?

Ultimately, when should I store my data as JSON?

P.S. While I understand NoSQL might be able to solve this issue, I'm looking for a MySQL answer!

Comment: In my experience it is always best to normalize a database from the start. Yes, it is more work, and generates more rows, but data-access is almost always easy and fast. In other words: You will never know, in advance, what elements of an address you need later for an optimized query.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - could you give an example of what that'd look like taking `based_in` as above? Does JSON then have no place in MySQL?

Comment: Books have been written on normalization. And, although the idea might sound abstract, there are very good reasons for it: Minimize duplicate data, minimize or avoid data modification issues, and simplify queries. JSON can be handled by MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html but your data would not be considered 'normalized'. As said, this has its disadvantages. You can use JSON 'sparingly' like Schwern says, in certain cases where not doing so would clearly be detrimental to your application.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. It is also too general.

Comment: @philipxy thank you for your input. If it's frequently asked, would you mind linking this question to the appropriate answer? While I disagree with you that "when should I store my data as JSON?" is too general of a question, I do understand how it may not have been formulated in a way that everyone could understand. The proof is in the great answer provided by Schwern, and helpful comments by KIKO.

Comment: A post can give an example of a fragment of this topic. My current generic comment re googling: As with every question, please google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Use the most frequently productive keywords as tags. Use the best search as a title.

Comment: Somewhat related:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Ultimately, when should I store my data as JSON?*

JSON types are there for when your data might not fit into a neat system of typed columns. You should use it ***sparingly*** when you're not sure what data you want to put in the table. Or when the data is inherently unstructured, this is infinitely more flexible than a key/value table.

In your example, you're pretty sure what you want to store: location information. That's a pretty well defined problem, and it is well handled by your `user_based_in` table.

A good example of when to use JSON might be logging hits to API endpoints. The parameters are decided on by each API endpoint, something the table cannot know.

```
create table api_log (
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    endpoint text not null,
    when timestamp not null,
    params json not null
);
```

[A Practical Guide to MySQL JSON Data Type By Example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/) uses a similar scenario.

Another example might be when you're just not sure what additional data you might want to collect.

```
create table stuff (
    ...normal table design...
    other json
);
```

This allows the application to speculatively store additional data, play around with it, and see if it's something they want to add to the structure. Once you do decide a given key/value is important, add it to the table as a column and transfer the data from JSON to the new column. This affords you all the benefits of a traditional relational database.

Let's say we decide `things` are important. We make a new `things` column. Set it to `other->>'$.things'`. And remove `things` from the JSON column to avoid data redundancy.

```
alter table stuff add column things text;

update stuff
set things = other->>'$.things',
    other = json_remove(other, '$.things')
where other is not null
```

Comment: I think you hit a great point with "when you're just not sure what additional data you might want to collect" - I guess that's where I'm at... I just prefer to do things right once so I don't have to go back and modify the back end - especially if its a public API that others depend on its consistency (versioning would work here but not for very frequent updates).

Comment: @Michał Yes, it gives you the flexibility of a NoSQL database with the structure of a SQL database. As for "doing it right once", that doesn't work so well in software; the problem changes, and your understanding of the problem changes. Your data store must change with it. "Screw it, store everything as JSON/NoSQL" is one way to handle that. Or it's handled with [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), [models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and [micro-services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).